# jQuery Selecting the first child with a specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I have a form in HTML with multiple inputs of type submit:

```
<form id = "myForm1" action="doSomethingImportant/10" class="postLink" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="antiCSRF" name="antiCSRF" value="12345"></input>
<input type="submit" value="clickThisLink"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Don'tclickThisLink"></input>
</form>
```

What I want to do is select only the first input with type submit while ignoring the others, the snippet of code I currently have is as follows, note it is within a for-each loop that goes through all forms on my page, hence (this) to avoid confusion:

```
var name = $(this).find("input[type='submit']").val();
```

I'm thinking this already grabs the first input of type submit by default, I'm not sure if that assumption is correct or if there's a more formal way of going about it, thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try:

```
$(this).children("input[type='submit']:first").val();
```

Comment: I believe `$(this).find(...` would work as well. See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to see which you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

how about the `first` selector

```
var name = $("input[type='submit']:first").val();
```

Comment: Hey Zarembisty, tried adding that, but that caused my entire script to stop working.