# jQuery: find child and bind to event

Tags: asp.net, html, jquery-selectors, jquery

I'm trying to bind to the `change` event of what is rendered as a `span` by ASP.NET from an `asp:Label`. Obviously the container prefixes these controls with something such as `ctl00_`, but I don't want to have my script dependent on identifiers that aren't necessarily known.

The `span` is updated via the `AjaxControlToolkit` `PasswordStrength` control which uses the ID the an ASP.NET label to display its help messages base on an input control it is validating.

On looking into it a bit, it seems what I want is possible as the control has its own `div` container - I found resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766652/jquery-selecting-the-first-child-with-a-specific-attribute), [here](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) that indicate I can essentially look-up the child with a selector, the SO answer looked absolutely promising so I came up with the following which alters only slightly:

```
<div id="PasswordHelpContainer" class="passwordFailureNotification">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="PasswordHelpLabel"/>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#PasswordHelpContainer').children('span:first').change(function () {
        //
    });
});
```

Unfortunately there was no success in my efforts; the event just doesn't fire.

**What am I doing wrong here?** 
**And am I mixing `Javascript` and `jQuery` together?**

I know the second question might sound paradoxical to some but I'll freely elaborate if needs be.

Comment: When do you expect the `change` event be fired from a `span` element? I don't see a way that can happen. It is supposed to be used with input elements, unless if it is triggered manually...

Comment: Instead of `.change(function(..){});`, try `.live('change', function(){..});`, it could be that you try to add the change event when the span isn't rendered by asp yet. .live() will add the event to elements that will be created in the future as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://api.jquery.com/change/

**The `change` event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements**. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

So your event will never get raised, since label is rendered as `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from what you said jQuery does not fire a change event for that change on itself. You either have to `trigger` the event on the element yourself, or run the event handler from a different logic (probably ASP.NET provides something, I have no idea).

As far as jQuery is concerned, I am very sure a change event will not be triggered for what you described.

Also, you should've marked your edits with a "**Edit**" marker or something, it was very hard finding what change you made to the question.